# using clamp function in OpenCL code

Tags: c++, opencl

In my OpenCL code (which is not coded by myself, it's just an example code from internet), there is the following sentence to use the function of clamp.

```
return clamp(color,0,1);
```

However it seems that this makes error during compilation, so I got the error info message by using CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG from clGetProgramBuildInfo.

```
Error during compilation! (-11)
4483
build log
:211:9: error: call to 'clamp' is ambiguous
        return clamp(color,0,1);
               ^~~~~
<built-in>:3558:26: note: candidate function
float4  __OVERLOADABLE__ clamp(float4 x, float min, float max)   ;
                         ^
<built-in>:3577:25: note: candidate function
float4 __OVERLOADABLE__ clamp(float4, float4, float4);
                        ^
<built-in>:3556:26: note: candidate function
float3  __OVERLOADABLE__ clamp(float3 x, float min, float max)   ;
                         ^
<built-in>:3575:25: note: candidate function
float3 __OVERLOADABLE__ clamp(float3, float3, float3);
                        ^
:296:52: error: address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
                                r.origin = matrixVectorMultiply(viewTransform, &(float3)(0, 0, -1));
                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:297:62: error: address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
                                r.dir    = normalize(matrixVectorMultiply(viewTransform, &(float3)(x, y, 0)) - r.origin);
                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there any necessary keyword for using clamp function in OpenCL code? BTW, I'm using the environment of the Linux Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

Comment: You may find the source code from this site: http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1241/entry-2254210-realtime-raytracing-with-opencl-ii/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
return clamp(color,0.0f,1.0f);
```

This way we know for sure that 2nd and 3rd params are not ambiguous and that you are trying to call the function:

```
clamp(float4 color, float min, float max);
```

If this doesn't work, then see your color param, but the 2nd and 3rd param should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks, by your guidance, the clamp problem disappeared. Now only the last two error messages are showing (296.., 297..). Do you have any idea about it also?

Comment: in 296, what is r.origin?comment out 297, just for clarity. &(float3)(0, 0, -1) looks fishy. remove the &, or replace it with *. or even better, see what's a constructor for float3 takes, and do it this way, for example float3(x,y,0). are you sure that x,y are of type float?

Answer (score 2):

There are several overloaded clamp builtin functions in OpenCL; the compiler needs to select exactly one, based on the types of the arguments. Valid combinations are

```
T clamp(T,T,T) and T clamp(T,S,S)
```

where T is one of the OpenCL integral or floating point types, and S is the scalar type of an element of T when T is a vector type.

It would appear that your sample code was illegally mixing float and integer arguments to the call. The constants 1 and 0 are of type `int`, unlike 0.0f and 1.0f which are of type `float`.

See the [quick reference card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look the quick reference card you provided. I will be very useful for my work. Anyway, do you have any idea about the last two error messages?

Comment: &(float3)(0, 0, -1) is taking the address of a constant, which seems illegal; put that float3 value in a variable (e.g. float3 zerozero1 = (float3)(0, 0, -1); and pass the address of that variable e.g. &zerozero1

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same problems on the same piece of code (http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1241/entry-2254210-realtime-raytracing-with-opencl-ii/). It is written poorly and managed to hang my pc.

The clamp() problem is indeed fixed by making sure that the last two arguments are floats.

The matrixVectorMultiply() problem is fixed by changing the signature of that function. It originally is:

```
float3 matrixVectorMultiply(__global float* matrix, float3* vector){ 
    float3 result;
    result.x = matrix[0]*((*vector).x)+matrix[4]*((*vector).y)+matrix[8]*((*vector).z)+matrix[12];
    result.y = matrix[1]*((*vector).x)+matrix[5]*((*vector).y)+matrix[9]*((*vector).z)+matrix[13];
    result.z = matrix[2]*((*vector).x)+matrix[6]*((*vector).y)+matrix[10]*((*vector).z)+matrix[14];
    return result;
}
```

However there is absolutely no reason for vector to be a pointer, so you can remove the `*` before every occurrence of `vector`.

Then the code should compile, but the program probably still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not your issue, but worth noting: Between OpenCL 1.0 and 1.1 clamp changed slightly, so if you are not careful you can have code that compiles in one version and not the other. Specifically, in the OpenCL 1.1 specification, "Appendix F – Changes", "F.1 Summary of changes from OpenCL 1.0" it says "The following features are added to the OpenCL C programming language (section 6):", then "New built-in functions", then "clamp integer function defined in section 6.11.3"

So you're best off fully qualifying your parameters.

Related to this, in OpenCL 1.1 added (vector, scalar) variant of integer functions min and max, so don't use those in 1.0 (cast the scalar parameters to vectors instead).